# operation of prefix and postfix operators in c

Tags: c, prefix, postfix-operator

For this code

```
int j=2;
int c=(j++)*(j++);
printf("%d\n",c);
```

I get the value of c as 6

While for below code

```
int j=2;
int c=(++j)*(++j);
printf("%d\n",c);
```

I get the value of c as 16

Can someone please explain this case to me ?

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour.  There is no correct answer.  Compilers can do what they like; what they like is correct; you have no cause for complaint.  Different compilers will handle the same code differently.  They're all 'correct'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simultaneously modifying the value of a variable, and using that variable in an expression. As such, your code is exhibiting **undefined behavior**. Undefined behavior is exactly that; anything can happen. There is no logical way to predict what values will result from the code you have written.